# WPF DataGrid window resize does not resize DataGridColumns

Tags: datagrid, resize, wpftoolkit

I have a WPF DataGrid (from the WPFToolkit package) like the following in my application.

```
<Controls:DataGrid>
            <Controls:DataGrid.Columns>
                <Controls:DataGridTextColumn Width="1*" Binding="{Binding Path=Column1}" Header="Column 1" />
                <Controls:DataGridTextColumn Width="1*" Binding="{Binding Path=Column2}" Header="Column 2" />
                <Controls:DataGridTextColumn Width="1*" Binding="{Binding Path=Column3}" Header="Column 3" />
    </Controls:DataGrid.Columns>
</Controls:DataGrid>
```

The column width should be automatically adjusted such that all three columns fill the width of the grid, so I set `Width="1*"` on every column. I encountered two problems with this approach.

1. When the `ItemsSource` of the DataGrid is `null` or an empty List, the columns won't size to fit the width of the grid but have a fixed width of about 20 pixel. Please see the following picture: `http://img169.imageshack.us/img169/3139/initialcolumnwidth.png`
2. When I maximize the application window, the columns won't adapt their size but keep their initial size. See the following picture: `http://img88.imageshack.us/img88/9362/columnwidthaftermaximiz.png`
3. When I resize the application window with the mouse, the columns won't resize.

I was able to solve problem #3 by deriving a sub class from DataGrid and override the DataGrid's `OnRenderSizeChanged` method as follows.

```
protected override void OnRenderSizeChanged(SizeChangedInfo sizeInfo)
{
    base.OnRenderSizeChanged(sizeInfo);
    foreach (var column in Columns)
    {
        var tmp = column.GetValue(DataGridColumn.WidthProperty);
        column.ClearValue(DataGridColumn.WidthProperty);
        column.SetValue(DataGridColumn.WidthProperty, tmp);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this does not solve problems #1 and #2. How can I get rid of them?

Answer (score 2):

I have exactly the same problem as you but instead of listening to RenderSizeChanged, I listened to the SizeChanged event and it accounts for all of your situations.

```
dataGrid.SizeChanged += (sender_, arg_) =>
        {
          foreach (var dataGridColumn in dataGrid.Columns)
          {
            DataGridLength dataGridLength = dataGridColumn.Width;
            dataGridColumn.ClearValue(DataGridColumn.WidthProperty);
            dataGridColumn.Width = dataGridLength;
          }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same problem as you stated. I searched a bit in the internet, and probably find a solution. The solution actually works for me properly.
Set the * value from C# code.
Here is the code snippet,

dg.Coulmns[0].Width = new DataGridLength(1.0, DatGridLengthUnitType.Star);

It will set the 0th column's width to *.
Don't forget to remove the Width="1**" from the XAML page.

Enjoy Guru.

Answer (score 0):

The following override fixes the size problem for the width growing bigger including maximize. But still not the restore size problem.

```
protected override void OnChildDesiredSizeChanged(UIElement e)
{
    base.OnChildDesiredSizeChanged(e);

    if (e.FindChild<DataGrid>() != null)
    {
        foreach (var column in dataGridMain.Columns)
        {
            var tmp = column.GetValue(DataGridColumn.WidthProperty);
            column.ClearValue(DataGridColumn.WidthProperty);
            column.SetValue(DataGridColumn.WidthProperty, tmp);
        }
    }
}
```

PS this problem only arose for me when I defined a GroupStyle template for the DataGrid, so it seems like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

All DataGridTextColumn has a default MinWidth prperty set to 20. So, if you want to control width after resizing from max to min you have to specify this value yourself. My proposal is:

```
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Perfect&#x0a;column" Binding="{Binding SomeMember}" MinWidth="120" Width="120*"/>
```